# The Fourier transform of a triangular window function

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, window-functions

Windowing functions are explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) and they include plots of the Fourier transform for several windowing functions. For the triangle window  they provide
[image]
The above Fourier transform plot has a horizontal axis that goes from -40 bins to +40 bins, so this seems to be a discrete Fourier transform. However, I don't get a plot like that when I apply an FFT to 80 samples of a triangular window. I am further confused in that the graphic of the Fourier transform looks like a continuous plot rather than 80 discrete samples.

My questions are:
How does one create the plot for the Fourier transform of a triangular window?
Is the plot for a continuous Fourier transform or discrete Fourier transform?

Comment: This plot was probably done with lots of zero padding. Do an FFT over 16k points or so. This is equivalent to dense interpolation in the frequency domain.

Comment: Or check [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/triang.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the perfect fit, but a quick-and-dirty base to play on:

```
%nBin = 81;
nBin = 2049;

y=(20*log(fftshift(abs(fft(triang(81),nBin)))))';
x = linspace(-40,40,length(y));
basey = min(0,min(y));
ShadingColor = [0 0 1];
h = fill([x x(end) x(1)], [y basey basey], ShadingColor); 
set(h, 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
```

[image: triangular]

Comment: @Luarent Duval, The frequency plot at Wikipedia has local max as low as about -73 dB, and as high as 0 dB. The frequency plot you posted has local max as low as about -75 dB and as high as about +75 dB. Could the Wikipedia plot require a different interpretation?

Comment: The picture in wikipedia somehow shows the amplitude in dB, not its power in dB. I would agree to Laurent's interpretation, however, in case you want to recreate the wikipedia plot, do this: y=(10*log(fftshift(abs(fft(triang(81),nBin)))))';
y = y - max(y);